# BLE encoding issue between iPhone and Arduino

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am working on an Arduino based device that will communicate via BLE with an iPhone.  The device is based on the TI CC2541 chipset.  Here is the [spec sheet](http://img.banggood.com/file/products/20150104013145BLE-CC41-A%20Spefication.pdf).

I need to be able to send messages both from the iPhone to the device, and also from the device back to the iPhone. The messages are short ASCII strings. The device will only ever be communicating with my iPhone app, so there is no real need for all the GATT and CoreBluetooth stuff, but being new to Bluetooth that's what I'm working with.  If you know of a way to achieve simple serial communication, bypassing all the CoreBluetooth/GATT scaffolding - let me know!

Anyway, I've gotten so far as to be able to send messages from the iPhone to the Arduino.  But the messages arrive garbled.  For each byte received, the low 4 bits match the low 4 bits of the byte sent. But the high 4 bits vary.

Does anyone know the encoding that's being used here?  Or do you know a way to just have it send what I want to send, without this encoding?

Here are the details.

After connecting to my BT device, I iterate through all the services, characteristics, and descriptors.  Here is the code for that:

```html
#pragma mark - CBCentralManagerDelegate

// CBCentralManagerDelegate - This is called with the CBPeripheral class as its main input parameter. This contains most of the information there is to know about a BLE peripheral.


// method called whenever the device state changes.
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    // Determine the state of the peripheral
    if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");
        
        //  This could pass a list of services, but we will just check all BT devices found, at least for now...
        
        [self.BTManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");
    }
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
    if ([localName length] > 0 && [localName isEqualToString: BTName]) {
        
        // Connect to the borg.  Note the RSSI parameter above.  This is the signal strength.  Might come in handy!
        NSLog(@"Found our device %@", localName);
        [self.BTManager stopScan];
        self.thePeripheral = peripheral;
        peripheral.delegate = self;
        [self.BTManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    }
}


// method called whenever you have successfully connected to the BLE peripheral
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    peripheral.delegate = self;
    [peripheral discoverServices:nil];
    
    NSString *connected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connected: %@", peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected ? @"YES" : @"NO"];
    NSLog(@"Connected to peripheral %@?  %@", peripheral.UUID, connected);
}


#pragma mark - CBPeripheralDelegate

// CBPeripheralDelegate - Invoked when you discover the peripheral's available services.
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
    // Enumerate through all services on the connected peripheral.
    for (CBService * service in [peripheral services])
    {
        NSLog(@"Found service %@, %s", service.UUID, (service.isPrimary) ? "is primary" : "is secondary");
        
        // FFE0 is the service we will use to read/write
        if ([[service.UUID UUIDString] isEqualToString:@"FFE0"])
            self.txrxService = service;
        
        // Discover all characteristics for this service.
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
    }
}

// Invoked when you discover the characteristics of a specified service.
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    // Enumerate through all services on the connected peripheral.
    for (CBCharacteristic * character in [service characteristics])
    {
        // FFE1 is the characteristic we will use to read/write
        if ([[character.UUID UUIDString] isEqualToString:@"FFE1"])
            self.txrxCharacteristic = character;
        
        NSLog(@"Service %@ has characteristic %@", service.UUID, character.UUID);
        // Discover all descriptors for each characteristic.
        [peripheral discoverDescriptorsForCharacteristic:character];
    }
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverDescriptorsForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
error:(NSError *)error
{
    for (CBDescriptor* descriptor in characteristic.descriptors) {
        NSLog(@"Found descriptor %@ for characteristic %@", descriptor.UUID, characteristic.UUID);
    }

}

// Invoked when you retrieve a specified characteristic's value, or when the peripheral device notifies your app that the characteristic's value has changed.
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
}
```

And here is the output:

```html
Found service Device Information, is primary
Found service FFE0, is primary
Service Device Information has characteristic System ID
Service Device Information has characteristic Model Number String
Service Device Information has characteristic Serial Number String
Service Device Information has characteristic Firmware Revision String
Service Device Information has characteristic Hardware Revision String
Service Device Information has characteristic Software Revision String
Service Device Information has characteristic Manufacturer Name String
Service Device Information has characteristic IEEE Regulatory Certification
Service Device Information has characteristic PnP ID
Service FFE0 has characteristic FFE1
Found descriptor Client Characteristic Configuration for characteristic FFE1
Found descriptor Characteristic User Description for characteristic FFE1
```

(Question - notice that I'm printing UUIDs, but they aren't UUIDs, they are descriptive strings.  What's up with that?)

Somewhat arbitrarily, I'm picking service FFE0, characteristic FFE1 to use to send my serial data.

Here is some testing code I use to send all printable ASCII characters to the device:

```html
// Test sending a range of ascii values
-(void)BTSendTest: (CBPeripheral*)peripheral forCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic*)characteristic
{
    NSLog(@"Sending to peripheral: %@ characteristic: %@", peripheral, characteristic.UUID);
    
    for (int asciiCode = 32, i=0; asciiCode < 126; asciiCode++, i++) {
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", asciiCode];
        
        NSLog(@"%d) sending <%@> 0x%x", i, string, asciiCode);
        
        NSData* data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if(characteristic.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse)
            [peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
        else
            [peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
    }
}
```

And here is the output of that:

```html
Sending to peripheral: <CBPeripheral: 0x156b1e60, identifier = 91DCFDD7-767E-65B7-6A66-48B5C7555CDC, name = TestDevice, state = connected> characteristic: FFE1
0) sending < > 0x20
1) sending <!> 0x21
2) sending <"> 0x22
3) sending <#> 0x23
4) sending <$> 0x24
5) sending <%> 0x25
6) sending <&> 0x26
7) sending <'> 0x27
8) sending <(> 0x28
9) sending <)> 0x29
10) sending <*> 0x2a
11) sending <+> 0x2b
12) sending <,> 0x2c
13) sending <-> 0x2d
14) sending <.> 0x2e
15) sending </> 0x2f
16) sending <0> 0x30
17) sending <1> 0x31
18) sending <2> 0x32
19) sending <3> 0x33
20) sending <4> 0x34
21) sending <5> 0x35
22) sending <6> 0x36
23) sending <7> 0x37
24) sending <8> 0x38
25) sending <9> 0x39
26) sending <:> 0x3a
27) sending <;> 0x3b
28) sending <<> 0x3c
29) sending <=> 0x3d
30) sending <>> 0x3e
31) sending <?> 0x3f
32) sending <@> 0x40
33) sending <A> 0x41
34) sending <B> 0x42
35) sending <C> 0x43
36) sending <D> 0x44
37) sending <E> 0x45
38) sending <F> 0x46
39) sending <G> 0x47
40) sending <H> 0x48
41) sending <I> 0x49
42) sending <J> 0x4a
43) sending <K> 0x4b
44) sending <L> 0x4c
45) sending <M> 0x4d
46) sending <N> 0x4e
47) sending <O> 0x4f
48) sending <P> 0x50
49) sending <Q> 0x51
50) sending <R> 0x52
51) sending <S> 0x53
52) sending <T> 0x54
53) sending <U> 0x55
54) sending <V> 0x56
55) sending <W> 0x57
56) sending <X> 0x58
57) sending <Y> 0x59
58) sending <Z> 0x5a
59) sending <[> 0x5b
60) sending <\> 0x5c
61) sending <]> 0x5d
62) sending <^> 0x5e
63) sending <_> 0x5f
64) sending <`> 0x60
65) sending <a> 0x61
66) sending <b> 0x62
67) sending <c> 0x63
68) sending <d> 0x64
69) sending <e> 0x65
70) sending <f> 0x66
71) sending <g> 0x67
72) sending <h> 0x68
73) sending <i> 0x69
74) sending <j> 0x6a
75) sending <k> 0x6b
76) sending <l> 0x6c
77) sending <m> 0x6d
78) sending <n> 0x6e
79) sending <o> 0x6f
80) sending <p> 0x70
81) sending <q> 0x71
82) sending <r> 0x72
83) sending <s> 0x73
84) sending <t> 0x74
85) sending <u> 0x75
86) sending <v> 0x76
87) sending <w> 0x77
88) sending <x> 0x78
89) sending <y> 0x79
90) sending <z> 0x7a
91) sending <{> 0x7b
92) sending <|> 0x7c
93) sending <}> 0x7d
```

Here is the code on the Arduino side that receives the BT messages:

```html
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial bt(A1, A0); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial)
    ;
    
  Serial.println("BTTest");
  
  bt.begin(57600);
  
}

int rcvCount = 0;
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (bt.available()) {
    char _ch;
    while ((_ch = bt.read()) != -1) {
      unsigned char ch = (unsigned char)_ch;
      char str[2];
      str[0] = ch;
      str[1] = '\0';
      Serial.print(rcvCount++);
      Serial.print(") ");
      Serial.print(str);
      Serial.print("\t0x");
      Serial.println((unsigned int)(unsigned char)ch, HEX);
    };
  };
}
```

And here is the output of that:

```html
BTTest
0) € 0x80
1) � 0x81
2) ‚ 0x82
3) ƒ 0x83
4) „ 0x84
5) … 0x85
6) † 0x86
7) § 0xA7
8) ˆ 0x88
9) © 0xA9
10) ª 0xAA
11) « 0xAB
12) ¬ 0xAC
13) ­ 0xAD
14) ® 0xAE
15) ¯ 0xAF
16) � 0x90
17) ‘ 0x91
18) ’ 0x92
19) “ 0x93
20) ” 0x94
21) µ 0xB5
22) ¶ 0xB6
23) · 0xB7
24) ˜ 0x98
25) ¹ 0xB9
26) º 0xBA
27) » 0xBB
28) ¼ 0xBC
29) ½ 0xBD
30) ¾ 0xBE
31) ¿ 0xBF
32)   0xA0
33) ¡ 0xA1
34) ¢ 0xA2
35) ƒ 0x83
36) ¤ 0xA4
37) ¥ 0xA5
38) † 0x86
39) ‡ 0x87
40) ¨ 0xA8
41) © 0xA9
42) Š 0x8A
43) ‹ 0x8B
44) Œ 0x8C
45) � 0x8D
46) ® 0xAE
47) � 0x8F
48) ° 0xB0
49) ± 0xB1
50) ’ 0x92
51) “ 0x93
52) ´ 0xB4
53) µ 0xB5
54) – 0x96
55) — 0x97
56) ¸ 0xB8
57) ™ 0x99
58) š 0x9A
59) › 0x9B
60) œ 0x9C
61) � 0x9D
62) ž 0x9E
63) Ÿ 0x9F
64)   0xA0
65) ¡ 0xA1
66) ¢ 0xA2
67) £ 0xA3
68) ¤ 0xA4
69) ¥ 0xA5
70) ¦ 0xA6
71) § 0xA7
72) ¨ 0xA8
73) © 0xA9
74) ª 0xAA
75) « 0xAB
76) ¬ 0xAC
77) ­ 0xAD
78) ® 0xAE
79) ¯ 0xAF
80) ° 0xB0
81) ± 0xB1
82) ² 0xB2
83) ³ 0xB3
84) ´ 0xB4
85) µ 0xB5
86) ¶ 0xB6
87) · 0xB7
88) ¸ 0xB8
89) ¹ 0xB9
90) º 0xBA
91) » 0xBB
92) ¼ 0xBC
93) ½ 0xBD
```

So, ... putting all this together, it looks like hex 40, 60, or 80 (decimal 64, 96, 128) are being added to the bytes sent.  But I don't see a pattern.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to use GATT with Core Bluetooth. There is no other access to BLE on iOS. It sounds like you aren't converting the 8 bit ascii correctly. Which String encoding are you using when you convert your NSData to NSString?

Comment: Thanks. I tried several encoding types, including NSUTF8StringEncoding. The thing is, if I examing the resulting NSData in the XCode debugger before it is sent, the values look ok. Is there a particular encoding type I should be using?

Comment: Perhaps you could show some code, but it also sounds like the problem may be on your peripheral rather than in iOS

Comment: I can show code if you want, I left it out because the code is pretty simple and I didn't want to over-complicate my question. This is the device I'm using:

Comment: http://img.banggood.com/file/products/20150104013145BLE-CC41-A%20Spefication.pdf

Comment: Updated question with code and more info.

Comment: you want to write the contents of the data container to the device, not the data container itself. change '[peripheral writeValue:data' to '[peripheral writeValue:[data bytes]'

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it.  writeValue takes an NSData*, not a (void*) (which is what [data bytes] is).  I tried your suggestion anyway, and it crashes with EX_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Ok, I made some progress.  I had been using a baud rate of 57600 on the BT module.  I set it via an AT command.  If I drop the baud rate to 9600, it works.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using soft serial on your arduino?

Comment: Yes. What is the max baud rate I can use?  Sorry, I should have thought of that. Because each ascii value was consistently being read as the same incorrect value, I thought it was some kind of encoding thing. It didn't occur to me that it was garbled data due to too high if a baud rate.

Answer (score 0):

try to decrease the baud rate for ble communication. instead of 57600 use 9600. arduino tends to run unstable after 19200 baud rate.